# How to force Boost to use rpath?

Tags: boost, bjam

I have to build Boost outside the "usual" directory tree (i.e., `/custom/dir` instead of `/usr`), which is not that much of a problem: Just pass `--prefix=/custom/path` to `./runscript.sh` / `./bjam`, and there you go.

Or so I thought.

The problem is that some of the Boost libraries depend on each other, and - using the default build process going through `./bootstrap.sh` / `./bjam` - it seems that the `--prefix` path is not added to the library search path for the Boost libs, i.e. no `-Wl,-rpath` is applied. That means that Boost libraries depending on other Boost libraries cannot find those at runtime.

My application - linking those `/custom/path` Boost libraries - already fails at `./configure` stage because `libboost_filesystem.so` cannot find `libboost_system.so`, *even though* I passed `-Wl,-rpath=/custom/path/boost/lib` to my own compiler line (i.e. the correct path to the Boost libs, I double-checked that `libboost_system.so` is there).

Now, to avoid heavy-handed methods like setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I'd like to build Boost in a way so that all the Boost libraries have the proper search path for the other Boost libs compiled into them. However, I was unable to find the proper procedure for that. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I needed to do this recently for another project, although I needed to use $ORIGIN to make the path relative to the location of boost's shared objects.

This required the following on a bash command line:

```
./b2 hardcode-dll-paths=true dll-path="'\$ORIGIN/../lib'" --prefix=$MY_PREFIX install
```

Figuring out the magic collection of characters to get that $ORIGIN placed correctly in the shared object took a bit of trial and error, so I hope writing the answer here helps others to avoid fumbling around with this.

Comment: Thanks, this answer saved my day.

Comment: Indeed, and it surpassed the originally "correct" answer in helpfulness.

Comment: Truthfully, if I hadn't written this here, I would have forgotten, and had to figure it out again.  This way, at least I'll find it when I desperately search around the internet for what I did a year or more ago.

Comment: in new version this does not work. `dll-path="'\$ORIGIN/../lib'"` will translate to `-R //../lib` instead of `-R \$ORIGIN/../lib`

Comment: Wang, I could not duplicate your issue with boost-1.72.0, on a bash prompt, on a Mandrake Linux system.  Were you using bash?

Answer (score 6):

You can add compiler & link options during build from the command line with:

```
bjam hard-code-dll-path=true dll-path=/custom/path
```

There's a FAQ item in the Boost Build docs about this (see [B2 docs](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/master/index.html#bbv2.faq.dll-path)).

Comment: Ahem... apparently this stopped working with Boost 1.45.0 (exact same invocation). I could not find mention of any relevant changes in 1.45.0; do you by happenstance know more than I do?

Comment: Hm, don't know more than you do on this one. But if it stopped working, I would consider it a bug. And should be reported as such.

Comment: 1.62 is OK with this options: `hardcode-dll-paths=true dll-path=/custom/path/lib`

Comment: on boost 1.69 I need to use `hardcode-dll-paths=true` insted of `hard-code-dll-path=true`